# What´s the difference between string made by a struct

Tags: c++, string, char

In the college I saw that my teacher made a program making a struct just like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct string_
{
  char _string [255];
}

struct person
{
   string_ birthday[5]; 
   string_ name[5];
}x;
```

I think that he did it because it seems to be easier to manipulate the strings in that way...
The problem came when I did an exam just in that way and he said that it was unnecesary

How can I save the strings not doing that and not using the datatype "string". something like...?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct person
{
   char birthday[5][255]; 
   char name[5][255];
}x;
```

Comment: slightly tangential, but why does a `person` have 5 birthdays and 5 names?

Comment: At what stage of the class did he tell you that?  Because it isn't easier, actually, especially when you consider security vs all the (insecure) standard C library routines.  So maybe he just meant for that particular class - perhaps early in the course - for whatever he was showing you that day - that the char-array-in-struct thing was easier.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x sorry, my bad, the program was about capturing that information from 5 diferent people

Comment: It would be more normal to have `struct person` be 1 person, and use an array of such structs to hold multiple people

Comment: @davidbak Maybe that, im just new in this, thats why I was asking

Comment: @davidbak - What are you talking about "all the (insecure) standard C library routines"'?

Comment: Things like strcpy, strcat, etc. that don't have buffer size parameters and are thus buffer-overflow bait.  (Newer alternative routines are now available and preferred, but the originals still exist and are frequently used/taught in classes, textbooks, examples, existing code bases, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

It may be because you cannot return array (`char[255]`) in a function, but you can return a struct, that contains an array.

For example

```
char[255] foo(); // cant do that
char* foo(); // can do that, but instead of copying string, only pointer to its begining is returned
string_ foo(); // can do that, and whole struct, that contains char[255] will be copied (returned)
```

Comment: That's not a bad suggestion, given the context.